# Akveo Nebular Angular Theme update 5.0 error

Tags: nebular

did a regular npm install to 5.0 from 4.0 and this keeps happening
`../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/accordion/accordion-item.component.d.ts:35:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

35     set disabled(val: boolean);
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/accordion/accordion.component.d.ts:71:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

71     get multi(): boolean;
           ~~~~~
../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/accordion/accordion.component.d.ts:72:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

72     set multi(val: boolean);
           ~~~~~
../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/actions/actions.component.d.ts:39:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

39     get disabled(): boolean;
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/actions/actions.component.d.ts:40:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

40     set disabled(value: boolean);
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/actions/actions.component.d.ts:139:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
` ect...

Comment: i'm getting same error, did you find resolution.  It seems that upgrading your typescript version might work, but mine is locked to 3.5.3 because my project is Angular 8 and I can't upgrade to nine just yet

Comment: I'm in the same trouble, did you resolve this @Sevensnake?

Comment: Actually I don't find any problems like that on my way so far. Just migrate ang to v9 and nebular to v5.0 then https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error while building the angular project. However, my scenario was that I created my project with Angular 8 and added nebular in my project using :

`ng add @nebular/theme`

Obviously, it was not going to run because I had accidentally installed nebular latest version which is **5.0.0**. So, what it did, it replaced my **@angular/cdk** package from **8.0.0** to **9.0.0** which ultimately broke all dependencies.

In order to resolve this I revert back all the changes and installed nebular **4.6.0** which resolved the issue:

`ng add @nebular/theme@4.6.0`